# Using SUBSTR() AND INSTR() find end of string

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

I have a problem, to select a substring from a string. The string after equal. My example looks like this one.

```
string='test = 1234sg654'
```

My idea was to select the string after the equal "1234sg654", in this way: with Instr() find position of equal, after that with Substr(), subtract the string after equal until end of string.

```
equal=INSTR(string,'=',1,1);
aux=Substr(string,-1,equal); // -1 I thought that is represent end of line
```

But the result is not 1234sg654
Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `-1` for the *position* argument -- the substring starts that many characters from the end of the string.  You can just do:

```
aux = substr(string, instr(string, '=') + 1)
```

No *third* argument means "go to the end of the string".